# PHP/MySQL fetch and convert to csv with pipe delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a PHP script that is exporting a mysql query to a | delimited file.  This working great except for the last "column" is appending a | pipe when I don't need it to.

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT ColumnA AS Name, ColumnB AS Address, ColumnC AS Phone FROM Table1");
$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  if ($row == 0)
  $row++;
  $csv_output .= "id|";
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
  $csv_output .= $value."|";
  }   
      $csv_output .= "\n";    
}
```

The end result looks like

```
Name|Address|Phone|
Name|Address|Phone|
Name|Address|Phone|
```

How do I avoid having the ending pipe after the Phone| so it looks like this:

```
Name|Address|Phone
Name|Address|Phone
Name|Address|Phone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one.

```
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  if ($row == 0)
  $row++;
  $csv_output .= "id|";
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
  $csv_output .= $value."|";
  }   
      $csv_output = substr($csv_output,0,-1);
      $csv_output .= "\n";    
}
```